# Column 'RecordsDate.StartDateTime' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

*sorry the title cannot be too long so I have to cut it down.
hi, I would like to get the total duration from my database table where the
dateID is 1 and the year of the datetime is 2016 using SQL Query in asp.net c#. I tried using the codes below but it does not work. It says 'Additional information: Column 'RecordsDate.StartDateTime' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my SQL Query please? Thanks a lot :)

```
        float totalDuration = 0f;

        string sQuery = "SELECT sum(Duration) AS TotalDuration FROM RecordsDate WHERE DateID='1' HAVING DATEPART(yyyy, StartDateTime) = '2016'";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            totalDuration = float.Parse(dr["TotalDuration"].ToString());


        }
        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
```

Comment: why not use where clause with and . You don't need having.

Comment: You use having when you use GROUP BY with aggregate function. where clause with and is what you need.

Comment: Hi @ Hakunamatata, @AkashAmin I don't understand what you guys are talking about. Can you guys explain to me using a SQL Query please? Thanks :)

Comment: `SELECT sum(Duration) AS TotalDuration FROM RecordsDate WHERE DateID='1' AND DATEPART(yyyy, StartDateTime) = '2016'`

Answer (score -1):

Provide group by with some column name from the table:
select sum(duration) as totalduration from recordsdate 
where dateid='1' having datepart(yyyy, startdatetime) = '2016'
group by ?